# how to filter out the dictionaries that have region field in them and put into new json file

Tags: python, json

{"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group13918.jpg61884":
    {"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group13918.jpg",
      "size":61884,
      "regions":
         [{"shape_attributes":
            {"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[181,175,170,179,179,196,185,185,203,222,214,182],
            "all_points_y":[176,182,198,182,192,211,189,177,172,165,163,175]},
            "region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[173,151,144,154,173,175,173,174,181,187,220,212,178,173],"all_points_y":[134,142,156,145,139,148,158,164,141,137,134,130,134,132]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[205,184,177,182,181,187,186,216,228,218,190,198,209,216,208,195,202,206,207],"all_points_y":[215,262,244,264,271,277,268,281,282,275,265,257,252,247,245,255,235,221,214]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[184,186,185,187,190,190,200,207,214,202,196,199,205,209,217,211,196,188,188],"all_points_y":[314,320,336,337,335,322,331,343,345,327,319,309,301,293,286,287,307,316,317]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[86,84,90,93,104,122,118,101,107,119,132,136,126,103,90,96,97,98,92,92,90,89],"all_points_y":[294,309,303,297,302,311,303,295,285,275,265,260,263,284,293,289,278,267,277,283,290,294]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[65,53,43,58,69,72,79,81,75,78,83,80,72,70,71,66,64],"all_points_y":[150,177,184,180,151,151,155,151,146,142,115,99,137,138,128,118,126]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[50,29,46,57,65,80,94,109,121,102,87,83,88,79,74,50,48],"all_points_y":[62,83,71,66,64,65,63,64,63,58,62,60,58,55,58,63,64]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[355,349,334,338,344,359,363,362,362,365,369,384,397,399,369,362],"all_points_y":[131,136,142,143,142,137,135,143,153,145,136,133,131,127,130,132]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[350,352,356,358,336,359,367,389,398,365],"all_points_y":[62,76,92,95,97,100,103,112,109,96]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[75,64,56,71,74,75,77,82,83,93,121,101,117,111,102,86],"all_points_y":[251,240,236,238,243,235,221,243,248,255,256,261,270,269,267,261]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[90,90,88,92,96,94,103,117,128,138,139,130,120,120,118,108,97,81,61,49,76,86,92],"all_points_y":[341,306,302,307,340,343,346,337,328,321,326,335,344,347,350,352,352,354,353,347,349,348,343]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[192,199,206,207,203,221,222,198],"all_points_y":[356,353,317,329,353,373,381,360]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[168,181,175,206,207,214,216,179,187,203,218,221,197,186,188,199,193,182,186,192,196,187,179,176,176,165,171,169],"all_points_y":[91,109,95,113,111,116,112,93,85,82,81,75,78,79,76,68,63,72,53,40,35,42,52,61,75,62,78,88]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[77,73,58,58,72,76,81,80,93,97,88,84,83,83,87,89,82,82,83,83,83,78,71,76,78],"all_points_y":[208,215,230,234,222,219,228,216,223,224,216,213,210,207,203,201,199,195,185,181,165,200,193,203,212]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[39,59,63,42,73,116,85,76,71,61],"all_points_y":[80,97,102,95,111,108,103,100,100,92]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[55,34,18,37,52,47,55,59,66,72,94,111,96,69,77,63,61,62,57],"all_points_y":[16,17,13,22,23,50,37,23,27,23,37,35,34,12,1,10,14,1,2]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[369,362,346,357,372,375,397,399,389,381,392,399,379,377,374,373],"all_points_y":[246,262,283,278,258,247,252,250,242,243,230,220,237,227,242,244]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[364,355,371,372,374,396,392,394,373,339,354,338,360,364],"all_points_y":[179,173,176,179,181,170,174,176,187,190,186,180,182,180]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[359,341,328,322,336,354,340,352,352,364,387,380,396,400,377,367,361],"all_points_y":[50,37,28,30,40,50,51,55,58,57,53,51,46,40,47,48,48]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[166,146,135,161,183,219,194],"all_points_y":[38,21,22,42,47,51,41]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[373,354,360,359,379,385,398,396,400,385,377],"all_points_y":[294,327,334,326,293,289,294,286,275,281,290]},"region_attributes":{}}],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14218.jpg59050":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14218.jpg","size":59050,"regions":[{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[0,43,82,54,61,50,7],"all_points_y":[42,60,85,65,45,57,44]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[142,128,149,154,164,173,172,158,169,194,156],"all_points_y":[176,207,177,168,178,188,176,163,161,157,153]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[158,150,127,126,141,143,162,165,165,164,171,172,187,218,206,173,168],"all_points_y":[113,119,131,138,127,128,118,117,130,143,133,122,126,139,126,116,116]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[60,58,51,43,55,63,65,77,96,81,68,89,105,115,92,80,69,71,58,39],"all_points_y":[152,163,172,197,176,164,156,161,163,156,152,147,142,142,139,143,147,138,150,161]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[68,81,82,74,86,109,122,108,72,53,34],"all_points_y":[192,166,173,193,195,196,195,203,202,199,194]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[68,72,78,81,81,85,84,82,79,77,78,75,72,71,64,63,67,63],"all_points_y":[239,241,252,271,276,265,256,248,243,240,227,230,231,223,206,202,226,233]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[202,180,187,171,191,191,226,199],"all_points_y":[365,335,353,347,365,370,391,368]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[54,60,66,76,77,83,114,93,85,58,57],"all_points_y":[255,263,272,283,288,289,305,288,284,253,257]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[48,49,50,52,52,52,54,84,90,94,70,82,59],"all_points_y":[99,85,70,52,82,98,101,110,113,115,111,127,107]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[144,160,166,161,157,164,169,183,203,177,170],"all_points_y":[199,197,197,204,224,209,201,205,212,199,195]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[136,165,172,157,150,168,176,178,204,219,205,186,173],"all_points_y":[223,241,244,245,245,249,249,248,257,267,252,242,239]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[77,84,86,83,86,88,89,97,112,97,112,116,102,93,97,106,96,90,89,78,78],"all_points_y":[307,320,324,329,329,335,327,333,345,329,328,324,321,320,306,282,292,309,319,305,309]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[146,142,135,120,137,145,149,156,161,160,177,191,171,160,159,156,160,155,153,145,133],"all_points_y":[72,83,89,92,93,85,73,73,69,64,53,32,52,59,61,59,45,48,65,65,61]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[109,116,145,154,175,190,205,186,164,161,165,155,151,121],"all_points_y":[2,13,20,20,16,10,3,8,12,11,1,9,16,12]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[350,355,358,361,358,368,372,378,373,369,385,381,384,368,365,358,355,355],"all_points_y":[66,74,90,93,108,98,118,121,102,88,75,73,69,77,84,66,59,70]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[364,345,343,350,366,366,381,398,374],"all_points_y":[145,165,191,168,154,152,150,144,144]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[368,365,373,360,379,399,388,398,398,383,376],"all_points_y":[128,151,174,166,183,180,176,162,158,171,162]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[344,349,374,353,370,374,353,355,351,347,344],"all_points_y":[295,298,320,292,282,274,283,272,255,273,290]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[358,365,378,397,386,374,370,389,398,388,370],"all_points_y":[268,271,287,304,288,277,268,265,258,258,265]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[358,357,357,362,365,372,377,388,378,397,392,375,359],"all_points_y":[20,48,57,64,24,26,26,21,18,11,7,14,19]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[366,358,334,354,361,371,391,363],"all_points_y":[326,338,347,349,348,331,305,333]},"region_attributes":{}}],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14219.jpg56266":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14219.jpg","size":56266,"regions":[{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[215,204,194,196,207,218,246,269,250,216],"all_points_y":[141,152,172,181,162,148,148,150,145,143]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[94,72,102,125,141,118,99,96,92,91,87],"all_points_y":[211,207,217,209,202,206,209,206,196,180,197]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[106,93,80,85,81,109,122,114,118,134,133,119,125,119,111],"all_points_y":[64,57,41,53,55,70,72,68,62,55,49,57,45,43,57]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[26,22,17,22,20,30,40,52,46,37,54,74,69],"all_points_y":[179,166,149,125,147,170,164,156,167,176,177,176,181]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[210,208,218,221,217,244,269,266,238,224,220,229,235,215,199,187,175,207,210],"all_points_y":[102,97,79,89,105,109,107,112,116,111,113,120,129,117,104,94,78,103,104]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[200,210,224,221,222,225,229,245,258,272,257,223,211],"all_points_y":[200,204,197,210,232,212,196,190,184,185,180,193,197]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[248,246,249,249,252,264,280,270,257,261,271,278,287,273,251,249],"all_points_y":[280,271,253,270,275,265,256,267,282,292,304,310,314,311,290,296]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[257,257,269,263,276,261,270,274,289,270,260,255],"all_points_y":[348,344,319,337,325,348,360,366,375,367,351,360]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[107,99,107,111,108,106,107,111,145,149,117,125,135,137,115,112,110,105],"all_points_y":[290,306,334,343,320,313,299,295,307,303,295,284,279,271,284,261,287,275]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[87,69,46,87,97,121,136,114,100,105,105],"all_points_y":[114,110,92,109,114,118,130,121,120,130,142]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[358,340,345,348,360,376,387,398,381,397,377,366,352,327,352,348,347],"all_points_y":[102,73,25,68,98,90,80,85,96,92,104,106,108,98,105,93,88]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[227,213,200,219,230,240,233,231,227,229,228],"all_points_y":[248,256,257,259,251,241,242,232,226,239,246]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[114,119,123,123,121,116,130,152,144,126,123,129,115,111,106,109,112],"all_points_y":[262,266,275,268,260,256,249,243,240,246,246,243,240,252,263,276,286]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[187,192,194,199,197,201,201,205,204,214,233,239,247,213,210,203,199],"all_points_y":[24,45,53,58,62,67,82,71,64,67,69,67,66,61,59,56,51]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[337,333,329,332,313,327,326,336,342,347,347,359,346,338],"all_points_y":[18,25,28,31,49,44,53,37,25,40,8,1,1,15]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[357,366,374,368,366,365,350,345,355,360,358],"all_points_y":[142,131,111,140,149,164,188,188,173,157,141]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[362,350,342,346,358,359,353,354,360,365,373,399,376,371,371,367,361,365],"all_points_y":[231,223,209,225,236,239,246,251,244,239,245,247,239,229,202,224,221,228]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[381,377,363,375,379,375,382,398,395,390,394,391,386],"all_points_y":[278,263,246,269,281,285,283,291,282,280,267,253,276]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[368,371,373,377,379,378,374,375,367,369,371],"all_points_y":[187,172,176,172,153,177,187,196,217,189,179]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[8,2,16,35,19,31,15,10],"all_points_y":[90,60,82,68,90,124,94,102]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[7,7,5,10,13,15,26,17,13,15,25,38,26,39,47,25],"all_points_y":[21,30,57,68,59,45,31,36,31,21,25,22,19,12,6,13]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[83,50,80,76,89,93,95,121,97,88],"all_points_y":[156,150,162,169,161,162,153,141,145,154]},"region_attributes":{}}],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14222.jpg52928":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14222.jpg","size":52928,"regions":[{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[90,87,78,82,100,119,122,138,150,131,144,143,136,125],"all_points_y":[353,351,346,357,363,368,364,367,362,362,350,334,348,358]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[108,86,88,66,95,113,116,123,142,110],"all_points_y":[316,320,321,321,326,320,324,318,303,317]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[114,121,135,127,123,124,134,135,108,106,104,81,64,87,106],"all_points_y":[278,275,262,274,278,279,282,285,283,290,285,279,265,275,279]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[98,90,94,87,67,86,99,103,111,106,105,107,107,101,101],"all_points_y":[227,229,234,244,263,254,233,236,240,233,228,224,200,196,223]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[83,83,74,59,64,76,83,87,108,127,101,104,114,99],"all_points_y":[187,193,201,224,220,205,200,189,193,190,185,180,176,180]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[83,80,78,69,70,42,79,82,87,93,93,98,95,119,139,126,99,94,109,111,87],"all_points_y":[132,135,133,142,143,164,143,139,137,146,163,149,137,136,135,129,131,129,121,117,129]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[86,75,52,38,40,49,75,72,85,88,91,91,105,100,116,119,93,92,89,79,84],"all_points_y":[87,87,76,61,69,79,92,99,93,98,98,95,94,90,84,78,87,72,63,48,71]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[183,180,179,159,181,183],"all_points_y":[107,116,121,143,125,117]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[172,187,202,193,220,234,195,207,212,200,197,192,192,176],"all_points_y":[100,108,121,110,113,106,106,102,95,99,91,96,101,101]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[221,219,225,231,249,275,261,240,245,252,256,244,234,230,223],"all_points_y":[253,265,287,295,307,312,304,294,286,279,270,281,288,288,270]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[227,217,245,214,217,217,252,262,264,259,242,219,191,210,208,212,217],"all_points_y":[182,194,178,211,224,238,237,233,236,240,243,243,230,234,211,201,187]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[73,57,69,68,75,77,86,84,77,74],"all_points_y":[48,38,40,8,29,41,40,50,67,74]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[378,376,379,382,385,390,383,386,382,376,377,368,366],"all_points_y":[113,126,122,136,148,140,118,114,108,87,104,104,105]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[366,348,370,377,377,392,398,377,375,372,359],"all_points_y":[67,77,73,77,72,69,61,64,57,66,52]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[384,380,350,347,369,382,397,396,391,383],"all_points_y":[161,165,166,170,171,170,191,175,169,169]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[174,164,150,134,159,180,182,188,199,206,190],"all_points_y":[21,30,37,34,41,24,36,22,17,0,16]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[251,241,221,234,253,258,262,254],"all_points_y":[382,364,350,371,393,396,372,386]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[362,341,361,350,362,368,400],"all_points_y":[22,37,26,58,38,26,27]},"region_attributes":{}},{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[375,395,399,387,397,399,384,384,382,386,379,379,378],"all_points_y":[212,200,200,211,215,221,216,224,237,251,247,219,212]},"region_attributes":{}}],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14243.jpg64869":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14243.jpg","size":64869,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14277.jpg67855":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14277.jpg","size":67855,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14278.jpg69263":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14278.jpg","size":69263,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14395.jpg61886":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14395.jpg","size":61886,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14456.jpg65359":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14456.jpg","size":65359,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14491.jpg56516":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14491.jpg","size":56516,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14543.jpg63875":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14543.jpg","size":63875,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14573.jpg61335":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14573.jpg","size":61335,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14574.jpg60216":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14574.jpg","size":60216,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14745.jpg60998":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14745.jpg","size":60998,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14807.jpg71491":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14807.jpg","size":71491,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14827.jpg56975":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14827.jpg","size":56975,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14839.jpg63985":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14839.jpg","size":63985,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14841.jpg64304":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14841.jpg","size":64304,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14845.jpg62241":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14845.jpg","size":62241,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14846.jpg64310":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14846.jpg","size":64310,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14849.jpg56749":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14849.jpg","size":56749,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14874.jpg70416":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14874.jpg","size":70416,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14877.jpg79349":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14877.jpg","size":79349,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14898.jpg68022":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14898.jpg","size":68022,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14900.jpg65983":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14900.jpg","size":65983,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14901.jpg63134":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14901.jpg","size":63134,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14906.jpg60710":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14906.jpg","size":60710,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14908.jpg65801":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14908.jpg","size":65801,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14909.jpg59864":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14909.jpg","size":59864,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14916.jpg60047":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14916.jpg","size":60047,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14919.jpg65406":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14919.jpg","size":65406,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14920.jpg63496":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14920.jpg","size":63496,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14923.jpg64592":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14923.jpg","size":64592,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14924.jpg62618":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14924.jpg","size":62618,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14926.jpg61413":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14926.jpg","size":61413,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14956.jpg66103":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14956.jpg","size":66103,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14958.jpg74140":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14958.jpg","size":74140,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14970.jpg77069":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14970.jpg","size":77069,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14977.jpg66001":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14977.jpg","size":66001,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14988.jpg65097":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14988.jpg","size":65097,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14996.jpg63719":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14996.jpg","size":63719,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14997.jpg58906":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14997.jpg","size":58906,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14998.jpg61388":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14998.jpg","size":61388,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15004.jpg61693":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15004.jpg","size":61693,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15039.jpg74887":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15039.jpg","size":74887,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15044.jpg80480":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15044.jpg","size":80480,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15051.jpg77339":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15051.jpg","size":77339,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15052.jpg76512":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15052.jpg","size":76512,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15053.jpg72703":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15053.jpg","size":72703,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15055.jpg74852":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15055.jpg","size":74852,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15056.jpg69793":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15056.jpg","size":69793,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15057.jpg70682":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15057.jpg","size":70682,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15068.jpg61392":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15068.jpg","size":61392,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15076.jpg63012":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15076.jpg","size":63012,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15077.jpg60828":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15077.jpg","size":60828,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15080.jpg59158":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15080.jpg","size":59158,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15083.jpg61089":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15083.jpg","size":61089,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15084.jpg61791":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15084.jpg","size":61791,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15086.jpg59381":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15086.jpg","size":59381,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}},"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15134.jpg73162":{"filename":"SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group15134.jpg","size":73162,"regions":[],"file_attributes":{}}}

Comment: Try using `len(data[p]['regions']) != 0`

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, if you try to load a file with a json object in each file, you'll get a decode error as it's not valid json.

Instead you loop through each line, then load the json and dump if the value of `regions` is `truthy`.

In python, empty `lists` are `falsy` so the regions which have an empty array will be filtered out.

```py
import json

with open('filtered_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('all_data.json') as json_file:
        for line in json_file:
            data = json.loads(line)
            if data['regions']:
                outfile.write(json.dumps(data)+'\n')
```

**all_data.json**

```
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group13918.jpg", ...other data...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14218.jpg", ...other data...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14219.jpg", ...other data...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14222.jpg", ...other data...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14243.jpg", ...other data...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14277.jpg", ...other data...}
```

**filtered_data.json**

```
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group13918.jpg", ...other data ...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14218.jpg", ...other data ...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14219.jpg", ...other data ...}
{"filename": "SPI_121218_SITE2_NDVI_25m_transparent_mosaic_group14222.jpg", ...other data ...}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the actual json file?

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 69)

Comment: Show me your actual json file.

Comment: i edited it and posted complete json file....i want only the first four filename's that contain region fields...and put these four into a new json file...can anyone help??

Comment: Check my answer below and see if it helps you @ara

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
data={}
with open('C:\\Users\\Takvaviya_PC_007\\Downloads\\via_region_data.json','r') as file:
    original = json.load(file)

for p in original:
    # print(p)
    # print(original[p])
    if original[p]['regions']!=[]:
        data[p]=original[p]
print(data)

with open('C:\\Users\\Takvaviya_PC_007\\Downloads\\pulse2.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by loading the json file as a dictionary,

```
import json
with open('<input>.json','r') as file:
    dct = json.load(file)
```

Then we iterate through the dictionary and append all dictionaries which has the `regions` key with a non-empty list.

```
li = []
for k,v in dct.items():
    #Check if regions key exists, and the list is non-empty
    if 'regions' in v and v['regions']:
        li.append(v)
print(li)
```

Then we save the resultant list to another json.

```
with open('<output>.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(li, outfile)
```